# c++ regex expression token delimiter

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to get my tokenizer working by splitting and keep delimiters such as semicolon, bracket, dot, and double-quotes.

```
string s ("main() a; i, Keyboard.readInt(HOW MANY NUMBERS? );");
regex e ("([.,;-]|[^.,;-]+)");
regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit ( s.begin(), s.end(), e );
regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;

while (rit!=rend) {
    cout << rit->str() << endl;
    ++rit;
}
```

When I compile it, it is kinda broken. Is there anything wrong with my regex `([.,;-]|[^.,;-]+)`? The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
main() a
;
i
,
Keyboard
.
readInt(HOW MANY NUMBERS? )
;
```

I'm hoping to output like this:

```
main
(
)
a
;
i
,
Keyboard
.
readInt
(
HOW MANY NUMBERS?
)
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest issue, really, is that you don't have your list of split tokens completed. What you want is something akin to `[.,;-:()\[\]"']|[^.,;-:()\[\]"']+`, which should be better able to break apart your string.

Of course, trying to parse a programming language (which is a type of [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)) using regex (which has less formal power) isn't the best idea. But, since I don't know the context here, I'm assuming you know this and that a regex really is the best way forward for you.

Comment: thanks. i figured it out. 
    ([().,;-]|[^().,;-]+)

Comment: If an answer is helpful, the custom on SO is to give a +1 or an "answered", so others know where to look when in a similar situation.